# Migrations in .net core with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm learning .net core and try to figure out the best practices for migrations. I come from Django and when when I had made a change to the database I would just do:

First:
`makemigrations` which is responsible for creating new migrations based on the changes you have made to your models.

Then:
`migrate` which is responsible for applying migrations.

Now I try to translate this to .NET Core and look at migration-commands in the Package Manager Console. I assumed that the equivalent would be to run:

First:
`Add-Migration -Name <myMigration>` *Adds a new migration.*

Then:
`Update-Database -Migration <myMigration>` *Updates the database to a specified migration.*

But then I get:
`There is already an object named '<modelName>' in the database.`

I'm thinking that Add-Migration didn't just add the changes to the database I've made in the Models-folder but seem to want to add everything from the Models-folder. So what am I missing here? How to I make a migration that only apply the unique changes to the database?

Comment: You are likely already have this table created. Migrations only work, when you do it from scratch, when there are no existing tables there. Then first migration creates all tables, and the following migrations update it. The migrations files are always generated as a diff from the **snapshot** file in the Migration folder, **not from the actual database**! If all did this in the past, then there may be an `__EfMigrationsHistory` Table or something along the lines. This table contains an a list of entries like `20170621093328_Init`. It tells which migrations have been already applied

Comment: Errors like yours can happen, when you apply a migration, then delete the `2017xxxxxxxxxxx_SomeName.cs` file w/o doing `Update-Database -Migration <previous_migraton_here>`, then run `Remove-Migration` and **then** create a new migration. it's easy to mess up, especially if you can't wipe out the db and reseed it easily and don't use an version control system which allows you to roll back to a specific snapshot. Also calling `Update-Database` with `-Migration` isn't necessary if you want to update to the most recent version. Only for rollbacks or applying not the most recent one required

Comment: @Tseng I could easily wipe my database, but how would I do this? Would I just delete all the migrations with `Remove-Migration -Name <migrationName>`, then run `Drop-Database`, and go `Add-Migration -Name Initial` ? After that, would just `Add-Migration` work as intended?

Comment: Yes something along the lines of that. You can of course just drop the database and delete the whole `Migrations` folder to start from scratch. This should work as long as you **never delete** a migration file manually and **never edit** the snapshot file manually

Answer (score 1):

You project is looking at a database that already exists. You may need to change you connection string / settings on the database your are pointing at.